# Clearing stuck paused download notifications by Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, notifications

I was downloading an app from Play Store which got paused due to an error "enable background data". I could get rid of this error, but in the notification center, I still see incomplete and paused downloads which I am not able to erase or remove.

I tried restarting my phone but it didn't fix it.

Comment: Did you try turning background data back on for Play Store?

Comment: Just wipe the data for the "Downloads" and "Download Manager" apps. That won't delete the files you had already downloaded, but only the download history. Note this is for just getting rid of the notification, it might or might not work for app downloads. It works for normal downloads, however (such as ones through the browser).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Android Lollipop, you must disable the battery saver to let Google Play download the app.

**OR**

Stay on the Play Store and wait till it downloads, not even let the screen shut.